# DevExtreme DataGrid: Show item only in add, not in edit popup

Tags: angular, devextreme, devextreme-angular

I'm using a DevExtreme DataGrid in Angular 5.
Add and Edit are activated and used in a Popup.
There is on field, which should appear only at the Add-popup, but not at the Edit-Popup.
In the normal DataGrid it is disabled anyway.

```html
<dxi-column dataField="Staff" [visible]="false">...
```

**How to enable the staff field in Add and disable it in Edit-Popup?**

Thank you for help!
Frank

Answer (score 2):

To accomplish this task, either use [onEditorPreparing](https://js.devexpress.com/Documentation/ApiReference/UI_Widgets/dxDataGrid/Configuration/#onEditorPreparing) or [onEditingStart](https://js.devexpress.com/Documentation/ApiReference/UI_Widgets/dxDataGrid/Configuration/#onEditingStart) and [onInitNewRow](https://js.devexpress.com/Documentation/ApiReference/UI_Widgets/dxDataGrid/Configuration/#onInitNewRow). Please refer to the code below that illustrates both solutions in action:

The first solution:

```
<dx-data-grid 
    (onEditorPreparing)="onEditorPreparing($event)">

onEditorPreparing(e) {
    if(e.parentType === "dataRow" && e.dataField === "CityID") {
        e.editorOptions.disabled = (typeof e.row.data.StateID !== "number");
    }
}
```

The second solution:

```
onEditingStart(e) {
    e.component.columnOption("firstName", "allowEditing", false);
},
onInitNewRow(e) {
    e.component.columnOption("firstName", "allowEditing", true);
}
```